# QML-How to change color of one point in chartview?

Tags: qt, qml

[image]

[image]

How to change color of one particular point in chartview in qml.i.e now all x axis values are displaying in black color but i want odd number to be displayed in red color.I want as shown in image where label colors in y axis are of different colors.
here is my piece of code

```
ChartView {
    id:chartView
    width: 2*horizontalList.width
    height:horizontalList.height
    antialiasing: true
    animationOptions: ChartView.SeriesAnimations
    legend.visible:false

    ValueAxis {
        id: scaleAxisX
        min: 0
        max: pointsX.length
        tickCount: pointsX.length+1
        labelFormat: "%.0f"
        titleVisible: false
        gridVisible: true
    }
    ValueAxis {
        id: scaleAxisY
        min: 0
        max: 1.0
        tickCount: 6
        //labelFormat: "%.0f"
        titleVisible: false
        gridVisible: false
        labelsVisible: false
        labelsColor: "#757575"
    }
    ScatterSeries {
        id: scatterSeries
        axisXTop:   scaleAxisX
        axisY: scaleAxisY
        color: "black"
        markerSize: 12
    }
}
```

As shown in second image ,the top line with red circle is a X axis(valueAxis) of chartview.i want to make the number inside the red circle to be in red color.

Comment: you could better explain what you want

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the Labels of the axes? Or do you want to change the colors of the circles that represent the series?, read [ask]

Comment: i want to change label color also red with red circle and others labels should be in black color without circle.

Comment: You could be precise in your answer, according to the image that elements you want to have another color.

Comment: yes,i want as in image

Comment: I do not understand anything, clearly indicate what you want.

Comment: please check i have edited question with one more image.I want it to be like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a different ScatterSeries with color value;

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.0

ChartView {
    title: "Scatters"
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: true

    ScatterSeries {
        color: "black"
        id: scatter1
        name: "Scatter1"
        XYPoint { x: 1; y: 1 }
        XYPoint { x: 2; y: 2 }
        XYPoint { x: 3; y: 3 }
        XYPoint { x: 4; y: 4 }
    }

    ScatterSeries {
        color: "red"    
        name: "Scatter2"
        XYPoint { x: 1.5; y: 1.5 }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want that label colors on x and y axis to be in red color.